# Can't install dlib for Python Windows

Tags: python, anaconda, dlib

I trying to install `dlib` for Python.
Early I've installed Anaconda, Cmake.
When I type this command in cmd(Administrator),

```
conda install -c conda-forge dlib=19.4
```

I get following errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyxz5.png)

Help me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the dependent library one by one and try reinstalling this library.

conda uninstall < dependent >

Comment: only conda? and what different between conda and anaconda?

Comment: conda is a tool for managing and deploying applications, environments and packages. anaconda is  Anaconda Cloud command line manager to upload,download libraries into open source repository

Comment: the conflict error you are seeing(mkl-service, numexpr,scikit-learn). uninstall them and reinstall in your conda environment.